# addEventListener, best way in terms of performance to pass variable to listener

Tags: ecmascript-6, addeventlistener

there are three ways of passing data to the listener while using addEventListener in JavaScript. Which one is the most efficient performance wise? Which one do you prefer?

**1st Way: With simple listener**

```
// With simple listener
const onBoardBtn = (instructionId) => {
    const onBoardBtn = document.querySelector(`.got-it-btn-${instructionId}`);
    onBoardBtn.instructionId = instructionId;
    onBoardBtn.addEventListener("click", openNextWindow);
}

const openNextWindow = (event) => {
    console.log("With Simple Listener: ", event.target.instructionId);
}

export { onBoardBtn };
```

Is there another way here to pass parameters to the listener?

**2nd Way: Event listener with anonymous function**

```
const onBoardBtn = (instructionId) => {
    const onBoardBtn = document.querySelector(`.got-it-btn-${instructionId}`);
    onBoardBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){openNextWindow(instructionId)} );
}

function openNextWindow(instructionId) {
    console.log("With Anonymous function: ", instructionId);
}

export { onBoardBtn };
```

**3rd Way: Event listener with an arrow function**

```
const onBoardBtn = (instructionId) => {
    const onBoardBtn = document.querySelector(`.got-it-btn-${instructionId}`);
    onBoardBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { openNextWindow(instructionId); } );
}

function openNextWindow(instructionId) {
    console.log("with an arrow function: ", instructionId);
}

export { onBoardBtn };
```

I hope for a nice debate so that we all can learn.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would prefer not to put arbitrary custom properties on my DOM elements. #2 and #3 are equivalent for all purposes.

Comment: "*I hope for a nice debate*" - sorry, but that's off-topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: That's exactly the question. if you want to pass parameters to your listener, using the first strategy, how would you do it? I just know about custom properties

Comment: As I said, I just wouldn't use that strategy at all. But if necessary, I would either use a [`data` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (for simple string data) or an [eventlistener object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)